# how to access stdout console in rails app running on Ubuntu VPS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, console

I need to run this `Rails.logger.info "SMTP_ADDR: #{ENV["SMTP_ADDRESS"].inspect}"` in `stdout console` on my VPS

I'm not sure how to access the `stdout console`
can someone please advise?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by `stdout`, but if you need run this on your VPS environment, `rails console` probably will help you.

For production environment, run it in the app directory:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails console
```

Omit or change `rails_env` variable for another environment.

Comment: I get this error when I try too run it `RAILS_ENV: command not found`

Comment: Make sure there's no space between variable name(rails_env in our case), `=` sign and value